# Compiling GCC 4.9.4 on Android fails with a conversion error

Tags: android, c++, c, gcc

I am compiling GCC 4.9.4 natively on a Android device, using KBox. Everything goes well, except for the part where `macro.c` and `files.c` should compile. Both errors are conversion errors, and apparently share a similar pattern. Here is the output of the error:

```
...
Making all in demos
Making all in calc
/home/rbox/devel/objdir/../gcc-4.9.4/libcpp/macro.c: In function 'const uchar* _cpp_builtin_macro_text(cpp_reader*, cpp_hashnode*)':
/home/rbox/devel/objdir/../gcc-4.9.4/libcpp/macro.c:253:34: error: invalid conversion from 'long unsigned int*' to 'const time_t* {aka const long int*}' [-fpermissive]
     tb = localtime (&st->st_mtime);
                                  ^
/home/rbox/devel/objdir/../gcc-4.9.4/libcpp/files.c: In function 'bool read_file_guts(cpp_reader*, _cpp_file*)':
/home/rbox/devel/objdir/../gcc-4.9.4/libcpp/files.c:728:27: error: cannot convert 'long long int*' to 'off_t* {aka long int*}' for argument '7' to 'unsigned char* _cpp_convert_input(cpp_reader*, const char*, unsigned char*, size_t, size_t, const unsigned char**, off_t*)'
          &file->st.st_size);
                           ^
make[3]: *** [files.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Making all in expr
make[3]: *** [macro.o] Error 1
Making all in tune
Making all in doc
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-libcpp] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
...
```

Could someone point me at why this issue is caused, and how I would be able to fix it?

Comment: It already points out the error, invalid conversion of long long, check your line 253 and 728, see who is converting it. Is it your running in 64bit machine?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer I am compiling on a 32-bit ARM processor device. I know that the error is a conversion error, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: isnt that long long is 64bit? perhaps change the data type that fits to 32-bit. I m just guessing.